# Golang: Unmarshal Self Closing Tags

Tags: xml, go, unmarshalling

So I'm trying to Unmarshal an XML file generated as a save file by another program in Google Go. It seems to be going great as the documentation on this is quite extensive: http://golang.org/pkg/encoding/xml/#Unmarshal

Still I'm running into a problem. The output in the save file is like this:

```
<location id="id4" x="-736" y="-544">
    <committed />
</location>
```

Instead of committed, a location can also be urgent or neither. The locations can also have a name and different labels, but these seem to be parsing just fine.
In my Go code I'm using the following struct:

```
type Location struct {
    Id string `xml:"id,attr"`
    Committed bool `xml:"commited"`
    Urgent bool `xml:"urgent"`
    Labels []Label `xml:"label"`
}
```

And although the Unmarshal function of the encoding/xml package runs without errors and the shown example is present in the data, all the values of both committed and urgent are "false".

What should I change to get the right values for these two fields?

(Unmarshalling is done using the following piece of code)

```
xmlFile, err := os.Open("model.xml")
if err != nil {
    fmt.Println("Error opening file:", err)
    return
}
defer xmlFile.Close()

b, _ := ioutil.ReadAll(xmlFile)

var xmlScheme uppaal.UppaalXML
err = xml.Unmarshal(b, &xmlScheme)
fmt.Println(err)
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

According to [this discussion](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/golang-dev/p3jJvHQ-MIE) this behaviour is not supported and the only reason you don't see an error is that you mispelled `committed` in the struct definition. If you write it correctly you will get a parse error because an empty string (the contents of a closed tag) is not a boolean value ([example on play](http://play.golang.org/p/0TDjML9ewz)).

In the linked golang-nuts thread rsc suggests to use `*struct{}` (a pointer to an empty struct) and check if that value is `nil` ([example on play](http://play.golang.org/p/FZQraMmKXc)):

```
type Location struct {
    Id        string    `xml:"id,attr"`
    Committed *struct{} `xml:"committed"`
    Urgent    bool      `xml:"urgent"`
}

if l.Committed != nil {
    // handle not committed
}
```

Answer (score 4):

For simple boolean values, i.e. value is true when an element is present, I have solved it this way:

Example XML:

```
<struct>
    <hide/>
    <data>Value</data>
</struct>
```

Data structure in Go:

```
type XMLValues struct {
    Hide BoolIfElementPresent `xml:"hide"`
    Data string               `xml:"data"`
}

type BoolIfElementPresent struct {
    bool
}

func (c *BoolIfElementPresent) UnmarshalXML(d *xml.Decoder, start xml.StartElement) error {
    var v string
    d.DecodeElement(&v, &start)
    *c = BoolIfElementPresent{true}
    return nil
}
```

This way, whenever `<hide/>` is present and unmarshalling is attempted, it just returns true. If `<hide/>` is not present, no unmarshalling is attempted and the default value `false` remains in the struct.

Note that you have to wrap your boolean values in the custom struct every time you work with it, though.

The `d.DecodeElement(&v, &start)` part seems unnecessary, but if you omit that piece of code you will receive an error message:

> xml: (*mypackage.BoolIfElementPresent).UnmarshalXML did not consume entire  element

**Edit:** Simplified version curtesy of @ShogunPanda:

```
type XMLValues struct {
    Hide BoolIfElementPresent `xml:"hide"`
    Data string               `xml:"data"`
}

type BoolIfElementPresent bool

func (c *BoolIfElementPresent) UnmarshalXML(d *xml.Decoder, start xml.StartElement) error {
    var v string
    d.DecodeElement(&v, &start)
    *c = true
    return nil
}
```

Note that you have to compare the booleans by using `if xyz == true`.

Comment: Your approach was great, but I found a way to improve it and avoid wrapping and casting. 

Just declare the custom type as `type BoolIfElementPresent bool`and in the `UnmarshalXML` method replace the second last line with  `*c = true`.

(sorry for bad formatting, but SO doesn't allow code blocks in comments)

Comment: Another little addition: with my approach, in order to check the value, you will have to compare explicitily: `if value {` won't work, `if value == true {` will.

Answer (score 1):

An easy way to solve this issue of empty self closing tags or empty tag is to use 
https://github.com/guregu/null package.

I am not a big fan of using packages for small stuff but this package have saved a lot of time for me

Here is how I am using this

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/xml"
    "fmt"

    "github.com/guregu/null"
)

func main() {
    type Result struct {
        XMLName xml.Name   `xml:"Person"`
        Name    string     `xml:"FullName"`
        Id      null.Int   `xml:"Id"`
        Height  null.Float `xml:"Height"`
    }
    v := Result{}

    data := `
        <Person>
            <FullName>Grace R. Emlin</FullName>
            <Id></Id>
            <Height />
        </Person>
    `
    err := xml.Unmarshal([]byte(data), &v)

    if err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("error: %v", err)
        return
    }

    fmt.Printf("XMLName: %#v\n", v.XMLName)
    fmt.Printf("Name: %q\n", v.Name)

    if !v.Id.IsZero() {
        fmt.Printf("Id: %d\n", v.Id.Int64)
    }
}
```

http://play.golang.org/p/xGKeIUM6NO

Full credit to guregu/null

Answer (score -1):

My case is different: I create app in golang as a forwarder to submit from api-a to api-b.
While api-a may generating a tag without closing and golang will not able to read it, which will not be read by api-b. Therefore I create two classes which one is reader and other is poster(sender).

maybe this will give some insight to others.

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/xml"
    "fmt"
)

type MyDataReader struct {
    Name string `xml:"name"`
    Lulus *struct{} `xml:"lulus"`
}

type MyDataPoster struct {
    Name string `xml:"name"`
    Lulus string `xml:"lulus"`
}

func ToPoster(m MyDataReader) MyDataPoster {
    res := MyDataPoster{}
    res.Name = m.Name
    if m.Lulus != nil {
        res.Lulus = "1"
    }
    return res
}

func main() {
    xmlString := `<data>
        <name>richard</name>
        <lulus />
    </data>`


    m := MyDataReader{}
    err := xml.Unmarshal([]byte(xmlString), &m)
    fmt.Println(err, m)

    mpost := ToPoster(m)
    output, errenc := xml.MarshalIndent(mpost, "", "    ")
    fmt.Println(errenc, string(output))
}
```

I create two class. One for retrieving and parsing and one for submit the xml.